# Set Value From Action Update, Delete, Inserted in Stored Procedure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, sql-insert

I have created my stored procedure, but I am confused how to set one column of from my table.

This is separate of my code:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_Gabungan]
    @REPORT_DT DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @action NVARCHAR(10),
            @insCount INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM INSERTED),
            @delCount INT = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DELETED)

    SELECT
        @REPORT_DT AS REPORT_DATE,
        FD.BRANCH_CODE AS [BRANCH],
        @action AS [ID_OPERATIONAL],   -- I want to set this value as 1(if there is a new input data, 2 
                                       -- (if there is updated data), 3 (if there is deleted data) from 
                                       -- from another field
        BR.REGULATOR_BRANCH as [RG_BRANCH]
    FROM 
        [DBO].[F_RR_FUNN] FD
    LEFT JOIN 
        [DBO].[MS_BRANCH] BR ON BR.BRANCH_CD = FD.BRANCH_CODE
    WHERE 
        FD.GROUP_PRODUCT = 'CA'
        AND Y17sa = '1'
        AND FD.REPORT_DATE = @REPORT_DT
END
```

How do I set column `ID_OPERASIONAL` as 1 (if there is a new data from another field), 2 for exists updated data from another field, 3 for deleted data from another field in a stored procedure.

ERROR from this code is:

> Invalid object name 'INSERTED'

Comment: Where do the tables `INSERTED` and `DELETED` come from? They are commonly used in triggers but don't automatically exist in SPs.

Comment: @DaleK Should i create tabel inserted and delete table?

Comment: @aldonnihut a stored procedure doesn't have an insert count nor a delete count, are you in fact trying to create a trigger? I suggest adding some sample data, and your expected results to try and clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DaleK yes, i want to create trigger on my store procedure.

Comment: I want to set value of ID_OPERATIONAL. The value is action from another field like BRANCH_CODE.If there is new data insert into BRANCH_CODE, value of ID_OPERATIONAL is 1, IF Value OF BRANCH_CODE Updated, Values id ID_OPERATIONAL is 2, IF Value OF BRANCH_CODE deleted Values id ID_OPERATIONAL is 3 @DaleK

Comment: Then I advise you to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and create a trigger on the table, not a stored procedure (or as well as).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

The problem the ERROR shows is that **you cannot use deleted/inserted tables in stored procedures but just accessible in triggers**.

If you want to have the count of inserted records or deleted records in a table there are two ways for doing this which the easiest one is:

---

Create you stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_Gabungan]
@REPORT_DT DATE,@DeletedCount INT , @InsertedCount Int
AS
BEGIN
...
```

Create a Trigger after insert and delete (so you can have inserted/deleted tables)
Then get the count just like you did in your code:

```
DECLARE @action nvarchar (10),
        @insCount int = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM INSERTED),
        @delCount int = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM DELETED)
```

Call your stored procedure in the Trigger and pass the @insCount and @delCount as inputs

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_Gabungan]
@REPORT_DT = GETDATE() , @InsertedCount = @insCount , @DeletedCount = @delCount
```

A similar question is this for more other ways like temp tables or...
[How use inserted\deleted table in stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21277748/6876710)

Also the link below is a question asking defining a trigger for both delete and insert so you can use both deleted/inserted tables together
[SQL Trigger on Update, Insert, Delete on non-specific row, column, or table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57954116/6876710)

---

Second way which is better when you are doing all these process a lot, is to get the log of your inserts or updates or deletes so you dont use triggers which reduce performance of your process.
(If usefull I can recommend some ideas for saving table logs)

---

```
    CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_Gabungan]
        @REPORT_DT DATE
       ,@DeletedCount INT 
       ,@InsertedCount INT
       ,@UpdateCount INT
AS BEGIN


 DECLARE @action INT

        SET @action = CASE
                        WHEN @InsertCount <> 0 THEN 1
                        WHEN @UpdateCount <> 0 THEN 2
                        WHEN @DeletedCount <> 0 THEN 3
                     END

        SELECT
            @REPORT_DT AS REPORT_DATE,
            FD.BRANCH_CODE AS [BRANCH],
            @action AS [ID_OPERATIONAL],
            BR.REGULATOR_BRANCH as [RG_BRANCH]
        FROM 
            [DBO].[F_RR_FUNN] FD
        LEFT JOIN 
            [DBO].[MS_BRANCH] BR ON BR.BRANCH_CD = FD.BRANCH_CODE
        WHERE 
            FD.GROUP_PRODUCT = 'CA'
            AND Y17sa = '1'
            AND FD.REPORT_DATE = @REPORT_DT END
```

---

```
   CREATE TRIGGER [YourTriggerName]
   AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ON [db].[tablename]
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
            DECLARE 
            @insCount int = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM New), -- New in MySQL is same as inserted,deleted,updated
            @delCount int = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Old),
            @upCount int =  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM New),

           EXEC [dbo].[SP_Gabungan]
            @REPORT_DT = GETDATE()
           ,@DeletedCount = @delCount
           ,@InsertedCount = @insCount
           ,@UpdateCount = @upCount
     END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I dont know how to create the TRIGGER. Please Help me

Comment: @aldonnihut Use this link https://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: Should i create trigger in my store procedure or out of store procedure

Comment: @aldonnihut here it is. may help you

Comment: your trigger syntax is MySql not Sql Server and wont work there

Comment: @MartinSmith the question tag was mysql then has been edited to sqlserver! I even searched to change my syntax from sqlserver to mysql :)

Comment: Ah, that sucks. I hadn't noticed that!